# How can we use managed prometheus of GCP to get cloud run metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, grafana, serverless

As I have been trying to interact with the cloud Run services which are kept in Authentication required mode to get metrics into Prometheus server but it is giving me the error

Approach 1:
Used a sidecar proxy to generate a token so that auth bearer can get its token for authentication but in spite of setting it the Prometheus target it is not able to request the cloud run which is kept in the required authentication mode to scrape metrics.
based on this [artice](https://github.com/DazWilkin/gcp-oidc-token-proxy)

Approach 2:
So I started exploring managed Prometheus Gcp tool but I could find any way to interact with the cloud-run services there is support for GKE so is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Sidecar is not yet supported on Cloud Run. For now, you have to hack the only one container to start different binaries concurrently with a startup script. That's true for the 2 approach. In the 2nd one, if you instrument your code with OT, you need a collector on Cloud Run that get the metrics and sink them to the targeted Prometheus (a sidecar). It's quite early for Cloud Run. maybe more announcement at Cloud Next in October.

Comment: This is a good question and Google's lagging with multi-port and Pod-oriented (multi-container) Cloud Run services. I've not used this for a few months but I wrote a proxy that authenticates requests to Cloud Run services so that they may be scraped by a Prometheus collector. The solution requires a Service Account to authenticate the requests. When I wrote this, I multiplexed Prometheus (HTTP/1.1) and gRPC (HTTP/2) traffic on the same port (another approach to complement @guillaume-blaquiere suggestions). [OIDC Token Proxy for GCP](https://github.com/DazWilkin/gcp-oidc-token-proxy).

Comment: hey @DazWilkin I used the same sidecar setup in k8 but still, I am not able to establish the authentication with cloud run  with OIDC token proxy what I may be missing

Comment: Interesting question. The proxy augments the regular Prometheus [oauth2](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#oauth2) config. I think (!?) to combine it with Google-managed Prometheus (GMP), you'd need to use [self-deployed collection](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-unmanaged) in order to be able to provide GMP with a regular `prometheus.yml` rather than e.g. `PodMonitorings`. It would be interesting to connect with GMP engineering and see whether there is a proposed solution.

Comment: Perhaps file an issue (or FR) on Google's public issue tracker for [Monitoring](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:187228)